# two vectors division

Tags: vectors

I need to write a method (in c#) for two vectors (A = [1, 2, 3] and B = [4, 5, 6]) division. MATLAB says that A/B is 0.415584415584415, so what exactly happens during this division? how can i achieve this result?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares

Comment: That not a division; its a notation in MATLAB for $A\cdot B^{-1}$.See the MATLAB help documentation for details.

Comment: I saw this A⋅B−1 notation, but in that case how to invert B when it is vector like [4,5,6] ?

Comment: The vector has no inverse in the proper sense of the word. MATLAB sees it is a line vector and hence deduces that it has to find the solution to the system $\underline{B}\cdot \underline{x}=\underline{A}$ and resorts to finding the least squares solution.